# Change from a ListView to a DetailView from an item inside the ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, listview, onitemclicklistener

I have a custom ArrayAdapter for my ListView and added a onItemClickListener to the ListView.

The Custom Item in the ArrayList for the ArrayAdapter contains more information then shown in the ListView. If the User clicks on an Item the CustomItemDetailView should show up.

But what is the best approach for this ?

I could start the CustomItemDetailView in a new Activity or just change the ListView with the CustomItemDetailView.

This is my custom ArrayAdapter

```
public class AuditModuleAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<AuditModule> {

    public AuditModuleAdapter(Context context, List<AuditModule> modules){
        super(context, 0, modules);
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

        AuditModule auditModule = super.getItem(position);

        if (convertView == null){
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(super.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.audit_module_v2, parent, false);
        }

        if (auditModule == null) {
            return convertView;
        }

        TextView amName = convertView.findViewById(R.id.am_name);
        TextView amMark =  convertView.findViewById(R.id.am_mark);
        TextView amId  = convertView.findViewById(R.id.am_auditId);
        TextView amCresits =  convertView.findViewById(R.id.am_credits);
        ImageView imageView =  convertView.findViewById(R.id.am_icon);

        amName.setText(auditModule.getName());

        amCresits.setText(String.valueOf(auditModule.getCredits()));
        imageView.setImageResource(auditModule.getStatus().getIconId());
        imageView.setColorFilter(auditModule.getStatus().getColor() );
        amId.setText(String.valueOf(auditModule.getId()));

        if (auditModule.getMark() == Double.MAX_VALUE){
            amMark.setText("-.-");
        } else {
            amMark.setText(String.valueOf(auditModule.getMark()));
        }

        return convertView;
    }

}
```

Here is the OnItemClickListener for the ListView

```
public class AuditModuleClickListener implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

    private Context context;

    public AuditModuleClickListener(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
        // Here what to do ?? 
    }
}
```

Here is a code snippet from the MainAcitiviy:

```
        List<AuditModule> auditModules = new ArrayList<>();
        AuditModuleAdapter auditModuleAdapter = new AuditModuleAdapter(this, auditModules);

        ListView listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        listView.setAdapter(auditModuleAdapter);
        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AuditModuleClickListener(this));
```

Comment: Start new activity from click

Comment: What Activity-Type should I use ?

Comment: AppCompactActivity.